# how can I embed 2 bars chart in html using java?

Tags: java, html, charts

I generate html page with java using `gagawa`

I now try to add a charts like this:

[image]

I have tried `org.jfree` framework

with this code:

```
private Img createChart(LatencyHistogram current, LatencyHistogram baseLine) {

    Img image = null;
    final CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset(current, baseLine);

    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
            "Line Chart Demo 1",       // chart title
            "Type",                    // domain axis label
            "Value",                   // range axis label
            dataset,                   // data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,  // orientation
            true,                      // include legend
            true,                      // tooltips
            false                      // urls
    );
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(java.awt.Color.white);
    // save it to an image
    try {
        final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(new StandardEntityCollection());
        final String pathname = Constants.HTML_PAGES_PATH + "images/latency_delta.png";
        final File file1 = new File(pathname);
        ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);
        image = new Img("latency", "../images/latency_delta.png").setWidth("400");
        return image;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

and got this result:
[image]

is there any way to create 2 bars chart instead?

is there a more clean and tidy free java charts drawer framework?

Comment: why do you use `createLineChart` you should use `createBarChart` to create a  bar chart

Comment: i couldn't find its docs. will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create a bar chart you should use

```
ChartFactory.createBarChart()
```

instead of

```
ChartFactory.createLineChart()
```

method .but since i don't know what is `LatencyHistogram` in your code this is not exact code.you have to currently use those data types .

for example following code will generate this

[image]

example code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class BarChartx extends ApplicationFrame {

    public BarChartx(String applicationTitle, String chartTitle) {
        super(applicationTitle);
        JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(chartTitle, "year", "value", createDataset(), PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        CategoryPlot p = barChart.getCategoryPlot();
        BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) p.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(255, 0, 102));
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, new Color(0, 153, 255));
        renderer.setItemMargin(0.03);

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(barChart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(560, 367));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }

    private CategoryDataset createDataset() {
        final String apple = "apple";
        final String mango = "mango";

        final String y2000 = "2000";
        final String y2001 = "2001";
        final String y2002 = "2002";
        final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        dataset.addValue(700, apple, y2000);
        dataset.addValue(550, mango, y2000);

        dataset.addValue(700, apple, y2001);
        dataset.addValue(550, mango, y2001);

        dataset.addValue(720, apple, y2002);
        dataset.addValue(570, mango, y2002);

        return dataset;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BarChartx chart = new BarChartx("example", "Bar Chart Demo 1");
        chart.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(chart);
        chart.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```